# I am resigning as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I don't want to give a big speech about this. In short, moderating is draining my emotional energy and I'm much less convinced of its value than I used to be.

**Edit:** Thanks for the warm comments! Just to confirm, I will remain as an ordinary user. Also, the diamond will disappear around Friday, I think.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Thanks for the effort you have put into the site. Hope that you continue to contribute in other ways. And I also hope that you enjoy your life as a grad student.

Comment: (+1) My upvote is intended to express gratitude for the effort you have put into MSE as a moderator.

Comment: @Qiaochu, I voted up for the effort you put in to make MSE a better place. Thanks and good luck. Hopefully, you will continue writing fine posts here.

Comment: I, too, am disappointed with this piece of news, and I am sorry to hear of how this thankless job is taking its toll in you. Thus, I would like to say thanks for all you've done for this site (mod and non-mod stuff).

Comment: I have to say I have repeatedly been amazed by the speed with which you provide on-point answers (which are often well beyond the mathematical maturity of a beginning grad student, and more like a postdoc) in the main site.  So if this re-allocates your time more toward  participation on MSE or MO that is potentially a benefit for a great many other people, apart from whatever reasons you may have for stopping.

Comment: Thanks for all the fish!

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work. I hope that you are still going to stay a contributor, and not go the way other former moderators.

Comment: Thanks for teaching us so much about how to fish!

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work! [2]

Comment: I sincerely hope that you will remain as a prolific contributor to MSE. Please don't let the draining arguments on subjective meta-mathematical matters obscure the fact there can be no doubt that your mathematical contributions have been superb.

Comment: Thanks for all the vegetables!

Comment: Sorry to see you go.

Comment: I'm sorry but not surprised to hear this. I think you've done a tremendous job both as a moderator and a user. Moderating this site is among the most difficult and thankless jobs I can imagine. Thanks for sticking with it as long as you did; I think the site is better for what you've done.

Comment: Thanks @Qiaochu.

Comment: I'm happy to read you will remain as an ordinary user.

Comment: Well, now that you're a regular user again... how about you run for moderator? I think you'd make a good moderator, and there are elections planned next week! :-)

Comment: And... Qiaochu receives a shiny Great Question badge (rarity on meta) in lieu of an engraved watch or other such retirement gift.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But I think you made a wise choice. You are too young to expend your energy on something like this. Go do something that's more creative and has more lasting value. Good luck.

Comment: I wonder: how long to moderators stay, on average?

Answer (score 118):

Let me just post in an answer what several other people have already said in their comments.

The work of moderator is, clearly, not easy and I can see that as a mod you probably see many unpleasant things, which users without moderator duties can easily miss. So I understand that there are rather unrewarding aspects of moderators work.

I have great respect for people who volunteer to do this. (I am sure I would never be able to do something like that both for the lack of time and lack of people skills.) I am very grateful for the things you have done as a mod - you had to deal with countless flags, discussions, unsatisfied users, merging accounts, etc. (There are probably many things mods have to do I don't even know about.)

Even if some people might have disagreed with your opinion on some things related to MSE and, on a very few occasions, with some of your actions as a moderator, it is undisputable that your contributions to MSE community (both as a moderator and as a user) are really great.

I hope that we will still see you here at least as an active user.