# 2017 Moderator Election: Nominating another user to consider running for a moderation slot.

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

I'm sort of modeling this post after Aaron Maroja's [2014 meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/2014-nominations-for-moderator-on-math-se) posted prior to the last moderator election, held in 2014. (So his post inspired this post.)

I think that some of the best leaders, and so too, moderators, emerge from among those who have been nominated by (a) peer(s), and only then, accept the nomination, and put themselves out there as a candidate.  Nominating another user is also  an opportunity to give note to a user whom you believe is great "mod material", whether or not that user accepts the nomination.

I have timed this post to provide a window of time, before the first day at which nominees must add their name as a candidate on October 2, 2017, for nominees to seriously consider whether to accept, decline, or ignore (all responses are valid).  By accepting a nomination, you are indicating you will enter yourself as a candidate on Oct 2, 2017 (or very shortly after).

I ask that all self-nominees refrain from posting here. All candidates will have that opportunity to self-nominate on Monday, Oct. 2, 2017.

If you want to nominate another user, please do so in a new "answer field" below.

Please refrain from one-sentence gut reactions, but try to provide a bit of thought and context to explain "what makes this user that you're nominating worth endorsing in an election?" Your post doesn't need to be any formal essay.  Again, this is an opportunity to toot the horn for exemplar users who are reluctant to toot their own horn.

Realize (as I've indicated) that any user you nominate has the option to accept or decline, or to simply ignore. Even if declined or ignored, it won't go unnoticed.

My hope, in this respect, is to widen the pool of qualified users who need to announce candidacy on Monday OCT. 2.

Comment: I'd like to ask in advance not to be nominated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm tempted to re-post [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17603), but I'm sure Martin will think about it anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer incidentally amWhy approached [him in chat about it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40276331#40276331).

Comment: @DanielFischer  I'm hoping that folks would scroll through the 2014 nominations, and honor Martin's very gracious statement which struck me as pretty clear (No thank you then, and no thank you now, in terms of not wanting to be nominated.)

Comment: @amwhy can I nominate you?

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra No.  I mean I'd very much prefer you not to do so. But thanks for asking.

Comment: So, you have no plans of being a moderator or you don't want to be nominated by me :-P

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra I'm sorry I was unclear.  I have absolutely no plans to run as a moderator;  I should have said I'd prefer that *no one* nominates me.

Comment: Well, that makes some sense. :)

Comment: @amWhy that's too bad. I think you would do a great job.

Answer (score 29):

[Accepted nomination.](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/6#post-2454864)

---

Well, I'll jump at the opportunity to nominate, specifically

- **[quid](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85306/quid)**

as a candidate in the upcoming 2017 election. I've been waiting for this opportunity to do so.

quid has, over time, been a very active member of mathematics.se and also on meta.mathematics.SE.  Quid has also regularly stopped in to the mod office chat, and other math chat rooms, and is very generous with their knowledge of SE, and of this site, so helpful that I've seen more than a few users in chat or on meta.math that assume (rightfully so) that quid is a moderator of this site.

I have never encountered anyone on SE who shares quid's depth of knowledge, range of application, and rare interpersonal skills that dissolve tension,  animosity, and defensive reactions in others and between others, through listening and rephrasing what is heard, e.g.

quid has also had plenty of background experience in terms of knowing and bearing the work entailed by a moderator.  [quid is currently a moderator on matheducators.se](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/143/quid), and has contributed significant (time and effort) at MSE, even while working **and** moderating another site. So quid is pretty dedicated to the responsibilities they take on.

Please explore for yourself any of the great meta answer's quid has provided, their answers on main, and note in comments the measured and sincere voice of quid, and some of the bridges they helped build between users who clash.

I am hoping against hope that quid will accept this nomination.

Comment: Thank you for this very kind nomination. I imagine moderating this site to be a very interesting challenge, and will explore the idea to run in the election over the next days.

Comment: @quid [You wrote](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17603/242) "I feel it is important [...] a moderator is actually moderate in his views..."  Do you *honestly* think that applies to you, given the many strong (and divisive) arguments that you've engaged in on meta?

Comment: @BillDubuque that's a fair point, and I am aware that my documented tendency to participate in animated discussions is something that could speak against me as a moderator. Honestly, I tend to consider it as my main weakness in this context. Not being new to the SE environment, it's not the first time I am faced with this. Here is what Todd Trimble had to say on [the post where fedja nominate me in the 2013 MO election](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/924) (tangentially I declined  and nominate Todd instead who became and still is a mod over there):

Comment: "I agree that quid is thoughtful (most of the time), but I also have found him (him?) at times to be unnecessarily argumentative. But overall I think he (he?) might be a decent choice for moderator -- if he were also to lose the pseudonym." Here is part of my reply (I snip the part on the pseudonym as I think it is less of an issue on this site)  "[..]ToddTrimble has a point that perhaps I like discussing too much for being a moderator (though I think I could control it if needed)." Since then I was selected to moderate MESE and thus was able to put my believe to test.

Comment: Moreover, while I am the first to agree that I did not at all times express my views in a moderate way, and I'll seize this opportunity to apologize to you and anybody else that might have been annoyed or even hurt by them, I like to think that my *views themselves* and more importantly the accompanying actions mostly are middle-of-the-road. That got a bit long. But I hope it addresses your concerns in view of the perspective of my nomination @BillDubuque

Comment: And so what about two current mods, @BillDubuque who use anonymity, anonymous user names?  It's not a deal breaker.  And there are many fine and admirable reasons for doing so in SE/MO communities.  We're at MSE, not the former, nor current MO, other net sites you've known for too many decades past.  If you look at elected mods across the SE network, anonymity of user name is very common.

Comment: @AmWhy fyi: The two other mods were not always anonymous, and anyone with basic web skills can easily find their real names. But this discussion is about the user  *quid*, not anyone else, so please stay on topic  And please read more carefully: my comments refer to quid's behavior on *this site*.

Comment: Then there's currently three mods anonymous. You're simply bullying in these comments. Perhaps you're still sore that you had no choice but to end your moderatorship?  But, you've given no examples, no evidence, nothing objective in your bullying.  If you are sincere about asking about one or two particular incident, than do so.  But you are making unsubstantiated claims in an attempt to trash a possible candidate?  Why not wait until your behavior is more visible, if and when quid decides to run.  The fact that you seem completely ignorant of some users need for anonymity, explains that need.

Comment: @BillDubuque that's fine and as I said on MO then "I do understand this to some extent" (re concern on the pseudonym). I think there is still a qualitative difference regarding this specific aspect between MO and this site (or other SE sites, for that matter), in that MO officially strongly encourages real names. Either way, there are plenty of  pseudonymous mods on SE (incidentally *including me*) and this point was debated in detail in earlier elections. I do not plan to continue the discussion right here. But I'm looking forward to your constructive contributions to the electoral process.

Comment: @BillDubuque to me the difference is clearly there, it is: I consider it as an impossibility for a moderator to be in permanent contradiction with a relatively prominent part of  official policy recommendations (this goes for other recommendations too). MO has a policy to strongly encourage  real names, this is not the case on this site (or SE more generally). This is the qualitative difference in my mind. One may see this differently, but this is what I meant.

Comment: I agree that moderators should be moderate, and believing one's actions are "middle-of-the-road" is still only a belief and should not be given the power to enforce it. **But** the objections based on "anonymity" are suspicious. Stack Exchange is (rightly so) very popular, and it's more than likely colleagues (and, still worse, bosses) are reading this.

Comment: @quid It seems you admit above that you've had problems controlling the power afforded by anonymity (and many MO users seem to have noticed that too given the votes on [your nomination are -16/+20).](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/924/6716)  How can we be confident that you won't have similar problems controlling moderator powers, esp. given that your abuses of anonymity on MSE appear far greater than on MO (presumably you know it is tolerated less on MO, so you are at least somewhat cognizant of the problems). Yet you still failed to restrain yourself even among professional MO peers. Scary.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque What is this obsession with anonymity? Are you sure "Bill Dubuque" makes you less anonymous than "quid" to the about 7 billions out there?

Comment: Did any of the existing/previous moderators gives a proof that they use the real name? For example, did they connect their MSE account to their professional website/ university? If they did not, I see no reason to ask for "real name" when one does not require a formal proof. @BillDubuque

Comment: @John: I can witness that at least two moderators are using their real name. I had a few beers with them. Enough that any real names would have come out.

Comment: @John It's not an "obsession with anonymity". Rather, it is a concern about *one* user's serious abuse of the power of anonymity. On such an [MO moderator wrote](http://goo.gl/BeQRyA) "people have indeed gotten annoyed with things s/he has said behind a veil of secrecy" (and that's a polite way of stating it). The large number of downvotes on quid's MO nomination presumably are related to those concerns. I participate on both sites, and my opinion is that quid's abuse of anonymity is far greater here than on MO. But kudos to quid for admitting above  that s/he has issues with such,

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Yes, I am aware of two existing/previous moderators who did mention their roles in MSE in their professional website. But there's only two that I am aware of. (Having a beer with Asaf is not yet a formal proof to me ^^)

Comment: @BillDubuque : Indeed, I am not around in MSE long enough to relate quid's comment to their anonymity. Indeed, I never care about the names. After all, there are users in MSE who seems to use real names and are way more annoying.

Comment: @BillDubuque I agree that the debate might be premature. I still would like to clarify what I believe to be a misunderstanding. The fact that sometimes I may be perceived as  "unnecessarily argumentative" is not due to me using or abusing a pseudonym. I know this since I was told about the same by some office-mates, among others.

Comment: @quid Given that many of your mathematical Stackexchange peers seem to think otherwise, I think of bit of serious introspection might be constructive.

Comment: Anonymity could become a problem if it were used to hide from the consequences of what a person says. But I don't recall quid ever doing anything approaching that. On the contrary, quid A) is generously sharing what they know about how the site works with all askers. B) when quid disagrees with my actions they argue constructively and basically seek to "keep me honest". I like to think Bill also seeks to keep me honest, but it is admittedly a bit more taxing to see that from his colorful rhetoric. Ideally a moderator would not need such guidance, but I'm a bit too emotional to do without.

Comment: Anyway, @quid, you certainly make a worthy candidate. If you choose to run, I wish you the best of luck. If you choose not to run, then I hope you still find the energy to continue helping the site.

Comment: I don't want this to drift away from the purpose of this post. I am also deleting some off-topic comments. Don't stray needlessly off topic.

Comment: I second this.  I do not always agree with @quid, but I think he would be excellent at moderating.

Comment: Thank you to everybody for the feedback. I decided to run. My nomination is up.

Answer (score 10):

It is a pleasure to propose [Martin Sleziak](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) (please take a look at his self-description and at his MSE participation statistics). 3 years ago, he [declined](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/2014-nominations-for-moderator-on-math-se/17603#17603) the nomination citing lack of time, but he left the door open for future elections. In case he managed to free himself from his various daily duties (academic or not), I believe that he would make for an excellent moderator for the following reason (listed in no peculiar order):

- he seems to have the type of personality that avoids conflicts and calms down the existing ones
- he is very active on both MSE and MO (and I am not talking about the mathematical activity, but about curating these sites): a tireless retagger, editor and voter
- he is a very experienced user by now, having been on MSE for 6,5 years (and having collected >40k reputation points)
- he is very active on Meta, which might not be necessary but which surely is a plus for the job of a moderator
- he seems to have an amazing memory, always remembering when a subject was already discussed on Meta several years ago, always finding duplicates on MSE
- very importantly, he seems to *enjoy* doing all the above.

I believe that Martin Sleziak has the best "raw material" for becoming a moderator, but he seems to suffer a bit from [lack of self-confidence regarding this job](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9267/i-am-resigning-as-moderator/9268#9268) (the lack of social skills would not be a problem, since he could very well focus on other aspects of curating the site, leaving direct human interaction to the other members of the moderating team). Ladies and gentlemen, a big round of applause to help him get over this unjustified stage fright!

Comment: I do support this, but be aware of [Martin's statement from 2014](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/2014-nominations-for-moderator-on-math-se/17603#17603): 
***In the future, when moderator elections come again, I will think about it and decide for myself. ... There is no need to make a post like this in the future***

Comment: @Joffan: I missed that last line. Leaving my post here, instead of deleting it, will probably not annoy Martin Sleziak.

Comment: Oh yeah, things can change in 3 years for sure.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for your confidence in me. However, what I wrote in [the post you linked](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/2014-nominations-for-moderator-on-math-se/17603#17603) still stands. Even if I considered running this time, I would not be able to do it because [I would have difficulties to find the time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/27082#27082).

Comment: It's up to you whether you keep the post here or not - but it's rather redundant, since I will definitely not run. (I should probably have said that quite clearly at least in the [election chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66291) or in a comment [as Asaf did](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27078/2017-moderator-election-nominating-another-user-to-consider-running-for-a-moder#comment108440_27078).)

Comment: That's a pitty @Martin, since I continue to think you'd make an excellent mod.

Comment: What @quid said, but without the typo in the word "pity". :P

Comment: @quid: Tell the truth now, you're only running for moderator so you can edit that comment, aren't you? :D

Comment: @Asaf there you saw through my plot. Oh well. :-)

Comment: @quid Ahem. I believe its about time to make that edit. :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt but, but the super-secret plot got busted; there's no point to it anymore! :-)

Comment: D= I guess so! @quid