# The unofficial 2021 elections nomination post

Tags: discussion, election

We will have an election soon to elect 2 new moderators. Continuing the tradition from past elections ([2014](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/2014-nominations-for-moderator-on-math-se), [2017](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27078/2017-moderator-election-nominating-another-user-to-consider-running-for-a-moder), [2018](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28686/the-unofficial-2018-elections-nomination-post), [2020](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/the-unofficial-2020-elections-nomination-thread)) we have a thread where people can nominate *other* people. Since candidacy is always voluntary this thread is only meant as a show of interest in possible candidates. You can still join the race even if you weren't named here, and you can decline participating, even if you were nominated by others.

---

**Guidelines** (Taken from quid's 2018 thread, again):

Some guidelines:

- Don't nominate Martin Sleziak.<sup>1</sup>
- One nomination per answer.
- In case there could be confusion, link to the profile.
- Try to give some details, don't only post a name.
- Even if you do not like some nominee, try to show restraint about it. Critical points can be raised. But this is not a thread to "grill" potential candidates, before they even decided to run.

Note that this is not an official thread. Everybody that wants to be a candidate must go through the official process. "Accepting" or "declining" a nomination here, does not mean anything in the end.

---

<sup>1</sup> The point is, don't nominate somebody that said they do not want to be nominated. If you want to approach them do so elsewhere.

Comment: When did Martin Slezaik say they don’t want to be a moderator?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17603/471884

Comment: Can someone with a lower amount of reputation vote to nominate?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: in this thread you can post an answer to nominate someone. However the formal nomination needs to be done by the candidate themself on the election page starting from 8th Nov.

Answer (score 39):

In the last election, [**Paramanand Singh**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/72031/paramanand-singh) missed out in a closely fought race with Xander Henderson. For sure, if they are available, they should be contesting this time.

That's because one can see their responses in the 2020 moderator election that are  [their nomination speech](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/8?tab=election#post-3763870) and [their answers to the 2020 questionnaire](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32200/316409). Not only are the second category of responses overwhelmingly well-received in terms of votes, their humble disposition has been highlighted in the comments section of the questionnaire. I recall an example where they voted to close and answered the same question, for which their apology on meta was well-received.

They are a relatively active member of CURED, have been an active site member for a long period, being able to write very decent mathematical answers particularly in the field of real analysis.

If I were to highlight possibly the most important quality that they can bring to a discussion, it is a degree of calm and a reduction of fractiousness among conflicting parties.

This user has a [moderator candidate score](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1080450/whats-my-candidate-score-for-moderator-elections) of $36/40$, which is usually considered appropriate for a candidate who wishes to run for the election.

With that, I nominate Paramanand Singh, in case it wasn't obvious already. I hope they will run!

Note : One last but important point is that this user is based in India, a geographical location that is somewhat far-flung from the regions the current moderators are based in (Western Europe, and North and South America) which would allow for moderation duties to be executed at a time when other moderators may find a time crunch.

Comment: Paramanand Singh is definitely a worthy candidate. I also agree with the sentiment of the last paragraph. I have been mildly worried about it for 5 years or so. Even though I also think that there's nothing wrong with the current moderators!

Comment: I am trying my luck this time too! In case people are wondering about my presence for some time (a month or so) on mathse, it is primarily to control my addiction to it.

Comment: Also thanks for the encouraging words and thanks to @JyrkiLahtonen too

Comment: Teresa are you interested in becoming mod?

Comment: @Maths I don't have the ability or the temperament currently. It will be a project down the line, but right now it would be too early to give it a crack. Nevertheless, I thank you for asking!

Comment: What's the "candidate score" and what's the rationale for how it's computed? The link only goes to a query page.

Comment: @user7530 See [What are the details on the “candidate score” which shows during an election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252641/986753) on [metase].

Comment: Nomination post: https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9?tab=nomination#post-4301924

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the confirmation and the link.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Glad to see you're running again. I'll confess that your and my positions don't agree in every case, but the incredible amount of goodwill you bring to your interactions wins you my vote. Good luck, and I hope you don't get burned out if you do become a moderator. :-)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: thanks a lot for your support! I believe difference of opinion is important and it allows both parties to widen their outlook. And we can always have a healthy discussion to reach some common ground.

Answer (score -5):

I nominate  [Shaun](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/104041/shaun) .$5,231$ posts edited and $2,079$ helpful flags.He is very active in Maths.SE

Comment: Hopefully our mods are more than just active - do you have specific reasons for this nomination besides activity levels?

Comment: @KReiser  I think $5,231$ posts edited and $2,079$ helpful flags are sufficient to claim he is eligible for Moderator. Also, I don't know him personally. How can   I write down a detailed explanation of his character?

Comment: @KReiser Also,$2079$ helpful flags is not an easy job

Comment: Surely you know more than just the number of edits and helpful flags a user has made (which can be done without needing to become a moderator) to be suggesting they become a moderator (which itself is a lot more involved than this)? "Moderator" is not a fancy title for people who reach a certain threshold of proper small actions, it is a role that requires ongoing suitability to make proper big actions.

Comment: Shaun stood last time, but withdrew before the vote. You can find his answers to the questionnaire [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32259/10513) (high-rep. users only).

Comment: okay @user1729 thank you for giving me this information

Comment: It is indeed not difficult to get a lot of helpful flags.